# Display all subcategories from parent category

Tags: categories

I have 20 subcategories from a parent category, and they are like that
Parent

- September
- November
- … up to 20

Here is the code that try it to display, but I get only 1 category instead

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories('child_of=505');
foreach($categories as $category): ?>

    <div class="qitem">
        <a href="<?php get_category_link( $category->term_id ); ?>" title="<?php echo $category->name; ?>">
            <?php echo $category->name; ?>
        </a>
        <h4>
            <span class="caption">
                <?php echo $category->name; ?>
            </span>
        </h4>
        <p>
            <span class="caption">
                <?php echo $category->description; ?>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Is this the complete code? You're missing an `endforeach`.

Comment: I missed to put the endforeach in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_categories()` uses `get_terms()` so the array argument you can pass it will be the same.
From the documentation the array can have a property `hide_empty`, by default its `true`.
I'm guessing that those categories have no posts attached to it, if that is the case you will need to set it to `false`.
The code would be like this.

```php
get_categories([
    'child_of'   => 505,
    'hide_empty' => false
]);
```

### Update

If you want to order the results you can add `order` to the array, the default value is `ASC` so you will need to set it to `DESC`.

```php
get_categories([
    'child_of'   => 505,
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'order'      => 'DESC'
]);
```

You can check [WP_Term_Query::__construct( string|array $query = '' )](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/) for all the available arguments you can use.

Comment: Its works,Thanks. Any chance to display on DESC order?

Comment: Find it 'order'=> 'DESC'

Comment: One more question the href is not working. It send to /blog

Comment: @DigitalPoint the problem is `<?php get_category_link( $category->term_id ); ?>`, this returns the value but you never outputed it. you can do `<?php echo get_category_link( $category->term_id ); ?>` , or my personal preference `<?= get_category_link( $category->term_id ); ?>`

Comment: Oh, ok lol. Thanks so much